# how do I place an input that filters my markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have two dropdown menu that allows me to filter markers. I would like to add an input that allows users to type in values for another parameter. the parameter I have contains U.S. zip code, but some of them containers more than one zip code.
For example
A. 48333
B. 49272, 39847
C. 47483, 30494,48333
what I would like is that when user type in the zip code value, only markers that contains this zip code will show. so if I type 48333, point A and C will be shown and B is hidden.
I am not sure what method I should add for this functionality. I don't think I can use

```
marker.<zipcode value> == <zipcode value> || 
<zipcode value>.length === 0
```

because the values user enter may not absolutely equal to the value I have.

```
filterMarkers = function (gender, people) {
for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender_filter").value;
    var people = document.getElementById("people_filter").value;
    var service = document.getElementById("filterzipcode").value;
    infowindow.close();

    // If is same category or category not picked
    if( (marker.gender == gender || gender.length === 0
        )&& (
        marker.people == people || people.length === 0
        )&&(marker.service contains any value that users include) {
        marker.setVisible(true);
        console.log('vis');
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
        marker.setVisible(false);
        console.log('hide');
    }
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
}
```

Thank you inadvance

Comment: You could use the old Regex hammer to hit that search nail on the head. var serviceSearchRegex = new RegExp(service); ..... &&(serviceSearchRegex.test(marker.service)) { ..... of course you may need to escape reserved regex operators if you're expecting complex input.

Comment: hi, so I have this now. var serviceSearch = new RegExp("filterzipcode"); ....serviceSearch.test(marker.service))){ ..... and my div is <div class="filterzipcode" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
            <input class="typedata" type ="text" placeholder="search for zip code">
        </div>                    when I enter a zipcode value to the input and press enter, I noticed all of my points are hidden. even with the other two filters that I have originally, no points are shown

Comment: new RegExp("filterzipcode") is looking to match "filterzipcode" as a string.  You need to pass the value of the input field to the RegExp object... eg. new RegExp(document.getElementById("filterzipcode").value).

Comment: an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" occurs for the code        var serviceSearch = new RegExp(document.getElementById("filterzipcode").value);  Do I also need to modify my div as well? not sure if I need to use onchange.  thanks

Comment: I noticed that I did not assign an id to my input, so I change it to var serviceSearch = new RegExp(document.getElementById("zipcode_filter").value); The other two filters work fine. However, when I tried to type any zipcode values in the input, either partial or full value, all markers are hidden. I am not sure what this is happening

Comment: What does marker.service contain? Is there a zipcode in there?

Comment: yes, I have an array with zip code values. but almost all markers have more than one zip code value.it looks like this '48227, 48235, 48219, 48223'

Comment: Ok, regex works on strings you could concatenate the array first before testing it. e.g. serviceSearch.test(marker.service.join(" "));

Comment: I have an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
I then tried to do this:             serviceSearch.test(Number(marker.service.join(""))), it still have this error message, when I click on the filter, it does not hide markers but does pan to the filtered marker. sorry that I do not have a lot of experience in this, I really thank you for your time and effort

Comment: So in some instances marker.service is not an array, or string, or even defined at all. Your logic needs to be updated to take this into account, or set marker.service = [] on all instances of marker when they are created.

Comment: hi, I tried putting marker.service=[]; into my filerMarkers function. when I enter values into the input, all my points are hidden and no error msg. do you mind looking into my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/maiiiii/3f7qoscy/      ? thank you again

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/k3mt8h9p/1/ --- i couldn't help but re-factor a bit... let me know if something doesn't make sense :)

Comment: omg, it works!!!! I have been struggling with this for days. really appreciate you spending the day helping me!!!! :)

Comment: hi again, @Synthetx. I wonder if you can help me in this. I would like to show marker info after points are filtered. such as if I select a female point. I then would like to tell user something similar to : you have selected " program A, and it is located in A". the closest example I found from Google Map is this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features. since I already have a filter function, how do I defined the text variable shown in the link?

Comment: Hey Maggster, Fiddle updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/gf9o3k0q/2/

Comment: thank you so much Synthetx. I really appreciate your help. good day!!

Comment: hi @Synthetx. I would like users to select group first, and only values of selected group(s) will show up in the second drop down. I have 2 simple select dropdowns and the values changed when group is selected, but my points are not hidden/shown after the second selection. https://jsfiddle.net/maiiiii/712gL4kd/6/